# Extra 2 Rep on SO Today?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I had reached the daily 200 rep score on SO today (confirmed by the 4th upvote on a post not adding any rep.) The 5th upvote on that same post, though, added 2 additional rep. Any ideas what might have happened? Could someone have downvoted (didn't see that, though) then the upvote added 2 rep, and then the downvoter removed their vote? I've definitely gained 202 upvote rep today. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. Page has the right number.

Comment: Happened to me yesterday. Started at -2 before breakfast. :-) My guess is that someone downvoted and then took it back, confusing the scoring. The rep cap then didn't hit at 200 but at 202.

Comment: Did you accept any answers today?

Comment: @Robert No accepted answers. I'm pretty sure it was a downvote/upvote/undo downvote combo. The recalc machine has everything right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure someone downvoted me, then someone else upvoted me, and then the original downvoter removed their down vote. In any case, the recalc machine has everything straight, so I think I can consider the mystery solved. Thanks everyone for the help and information.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably bug.

Trigger recalculation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) (button on the bottom)