# Extra two rep points for no apparent or recorded reason in meta

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

As you can see from the picture below, I have an extra two rep points today, not linked to any post. I have not accepted any answers today or done anything to warrant the points. I tried the [rep recalc link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) recommended in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101248/extra-2-rep-on-so-today), suitably adjusted to be for meta not SO. The 2 points don't show up there, and wouldn't add up to the total anyway, but it does appear in my profile and in the popup box that appears when you hover over your username.

Is there a reason this might have happened? Is it just a transient weird thing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a transient thing...for performance reasons we cache the daily totals for 10 minutes, in the case of reversed votes this can result in some temporary oddness in the now-empty day case.

We actually update the totals based on the details when in the pre-expanded sections...I'll make this work with completely empty days as well then mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

*Update*: Starting with the next build this will properly show a `0` when cases like this happen (the only votes in a day were later reversed, after the totals were cached).