# Why do I get only one reputation for up-vote on my answer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, stack-exchange, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [Extra 2 Rep on SO Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101248/extra-2-rep-on-so-today)

I have many upvotes today on my answers, but then, I am getting only one reputation for every upvote, I was getting 10 reputations per answer upvote, why?

Comment: I didn't find this in the questions.

Comment: @ChrisF no, in the simple case he should have reached 230 (200 from upvotes and 30 from accepted answers) however he has 232. Those extra 2 points are not trivial, but already [reported before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101248/extra-2-rep-on-so-today).

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan if you'll go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and click "Trigger Reputation Recalc" you'll most likely lose 2 points, the +2 shouldn't be there. It will happen sooner or later anyway.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Ah, wrong dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you have reached 200 up vote rep/cap

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. He should have reached 230 (200 from upvotes and 30 from accepted answers) however he has 232. Those extra 2 points are not trivial, but already [reported before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101248/extra-2-rep-on-so-today).